# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory on fresh database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-migrations

Folder structure:

```
-project/
  -project/
    -manage.py
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
    -wsgi.py
  -apps/
    -user/
      -migrations/
        -migration files here
      -models.py
```

User model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone


class User(AbstractUser):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # user
    'apps.user.apps.UserConfig',

    # built-in
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # third party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

What I've tried (every new code block is run on a fresh database and without any migration files for the app user):

```
python manage.py makemigrations user
python manage.py migrate
```

---

```
python manage.py makemigrations user
python manage.py migrate user
```

---

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations user
python manage.py migrate user
```

And all of them results in the following exception:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration authtoken.0001_initial is applied before its dependency user.0001_initial on da
```

tabase 'default'.

Comment: as it is initial migration, I would delete users one and run a makemigrations only (all) in order to let django organize dependencies.

Comment: 3rd party packages come with migration files, the only app that needs migrations is users.

Comment: I think you'd try migrations without swappable=True. It is known to be delicate.